# Cat cable switch for wifi repeater and desktop

Tags: networking, lan, repeater

I am on the complete top floor of the building I live in and the router is located on the groudn floor. I have one cat cable coming from the router but the wifi here is bad. So i need 2 cables for my desktop that does not have a wifi card and also I have a wifi repeater that send a wifi signal from the cat cable connected to the device. Now i bought a Cat cable switch that will have the cable from the router in the input which switches the cable into 2 cables. one for my pc and one for my wifi reapeater. Now the problem is that when i connect the cable to the wifi repeater the internet on my desktop gets turned off. Is this because a switch is not able to have both connected to the cable.

Sorry for my english 
[Here a schematic drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr6KM.jpg)

Comment: What is a "Cat cable switch" and why didn't you just get a normal network switch?

Comment: https://www.coolblue.nl/product/363144/tp-link-tl-sg105.html?tid=pla-339428667814&ref=391984&gclid=Cj0KCQjwre_XBRDVARIsAPf7zZjC-AhKhCF13LzYHGyx0MgFTGLjPgNThHaQd5T7_KBLkQawwi_lamUaAqTcEALw_wcB this is what i meant sorry

Comment: English version https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-42_TL-SG105.html

Comment: So you have a cable from your desktop to the switch, and a cable from the wifi repeater, to the switch, and then the cable from downstairs, to the switch? The switch should have **3** cables connected.

Comment: I put a schematic drawing in the question. but yea i got a cable in the router to the input of the network switch that leads into 2 cables going to my desktop and my wifi repeater. if i attach the cable to the repeater the connection on my desktop dissapears. it used to work now for half a year but suddenly today it stopped as described above

Comment: @Robin, what's the make/model of the repeater?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the device on the other end of the cable only allows a single device to have an Internet connection. The way around this would be to get a router and configure it to run in gateway mode, such that the NAT in the router will appear as a single device. This router can then also be used to replace the wifi repeater if it has wifi capability.

Comment: It used to always work, but today it suddenly stopped working. people say it is because of a driver but i have never had to download a driver